# Addressing JSON data in supabase JS client

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, supabase

I have a column *guests* which contains json data of the schema first_name, last_name. Each row can contain multiple guests.

```
[{"last_name":"One","first_name":"Guest"},
 {"last_name":"Two","first_name":"Guest"}]
```

I'm trying to address the data inside this object. In the supabase/postgres console the following statement gives me results as intended:

```sql
Select *
from bookings
where ((guests -> 0 ->> 'first_name') = 'Guest')
```

When querying the same in supabase JS it doesn't return any output:

```js
let query = supabase.from("bookings")
                    .select()
                    .eq('guests -> 0 ->> first_name', 'Guest');
```

What am I missing here?

Also the statement to check if the json exists and is not empty doesn't work:

```js
.not('guests -> 0 ->> first_name','is',null)
```

I tried different approaches but it seems I am addressing the json object in a wrong way.

Comment: `from bookings` VS `from('get_bookings')` is one difference. Is the table named `bookings` or `get_bookings`?

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing it out. It was a typo while trying to generalize the code. In my code it is named correct in both places and other queries work.

Comment: After trying around for days the solution is stupidly simple:
The parser of addressing of the JSON structure via REST treats the whitespaces differently than in the postgres console. Avoiding spaces leads to the desired output:
´.eq('guests->0->>first_name','Guest')´

Comment: @Speaka If you found the solution in another thread here, link it and close this as duplicate. Otherwise, this qualifies for a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - post it and accept it, don't edit it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to the problem is to avoid whitespaces in the string:

```js
.eq('guests->0->>first_name','Guest')
```

Comment: It would be great if you could also provide some more details and possibly quotes/sources where you verified this. How's the whitespace processed when you *do* use it? Is `'guests'` becoming `'guests '` with a trailing space, `0::int` turns into `' 0 '::text` with both leading and trailing space as well as its type altered, therefore changing [`->`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) from an array element accessor to a key accessor?